# remove an image that appear on all pages

Tags: magento-2.1, php, category

This image appears on every page created except for the checkout page and the home page. I want to remove it or at least hide it. The image is not clickable.[image]

Comment: Please, check layout file for that location. Enable hits and checkout layout file and change accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the website, it seems that you are using MGS Molly theme. It applies the image via breadcrumbs.

To remove this, you would need to remove it from **`app/design/frontend/Mgs/molly/web/css/theme.css`** file.

The class which contains breadcrumbs background image attribute is **.breadcrumbs**.

After making the changes, you would need to flush the cache and deploy static content.

Please check and let me know if it helped.